# In App Purchase Server verification

Tags: php, ios, in-app-purchase, verification, storekit

I'm currently trying to verify my In App Purchase Receipt with the AppStore using server side verification (in PHP).

Here is my code:

```
// ViewController.m:
NSString *receiptDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[transaction transactionReceipt] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *verificationDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"receiptData=%@", receiptDataString];
NSData *verificationData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[verificationDataString UTF8String] length:[verificationDataString length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *verificationRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://update.csundm.de/inapp/verifyReceipt.php"]];
[verificationRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[verificationRequest setHTTPBody:verificationData];

NSData *verificationResultData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:verificationRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *verificationResultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:verificationResultData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", verificationResultString);

********************************************************

// verifyReceipt.php:
$receiptData = $_POST["receiptData"];
$receiptDataEncoded = base64_encode($receiptData);
$receiptJSONString = json_encode(Array("receipt-data" => $receiptDataEncoded));

$contextData = array ( 
                      "method" => "POST",
                      "header" => "Connection: close\r\n".
                      "Content-Length: ".strlen($receiptJSONString)."\r\n",
                      "content" => $receiptJSONString);
$context = stream_context_create (array ( 'https' => $contextData ));
$result =  file_get_contents ("https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt", false, $context);

$jsonResult = json_decode($result);
if ($jsonResult -> {"status"} != 0) {
    echo "Receipt invalid: ".$result;
}
else {
    echo "Receipt valid";
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting »Receipt invalid: {"status":21000}« Can anybody imagine what the problem could be? I can't even find information about this error code on the internet. I found one error description but they said that this is only for non-renewable subscriptions.

Thanks a lot, with kind regards, Julian

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding it on the iphone/client side first and then send the encoded data to php/server side. The output from base64'ing on object-c looks like the output from `chunk_split(base64_encode($receiptData), 65)` on the PHP side, so its slightly different.

I also tried encoding it on the server side using the above code but that doesn't seem to work either, even when normalising all the new lines to use `\r` and stripping any trailing white spaces before encoding it. Must be some tiny detail that I left out, anyway, just encode it on the iphone side and save yourself the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

From the StoreKitGuide:

**Status codes for auto-renewable subscriptions**

```
Status Code | Description
21000 | The App Store could not read the JSON object you provided.
```

Comment: As I already wrote in my question: I know it about auto-renewable subscriptions. But I want to know about the problem with others. And why would it not read my JSON Object?! Could somebody check my code?